# How to Change a css property based on a state of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm building a web page with gatsby which is based in react, and I need my nav component changes his sticky position to relative or auto, every time that I open the modal of the gallery component..but I don't know how to approach and solve the problem. The nav component belongs to the layout component which is Gallery's parent component...Here are the components involved:

nav component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Location } from '@reach/router'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import { Menu, X } from 'react-feather'
import Logo from './Logo'

import './Nav.css'

export class Navigation extends Component {
  state = {
    active: false,
    activeSubNav: false,
    currentPath: false
  }

  componentDidMount = () =>
    this.setState({ currentPath: this.props.location.pathname })

  handleMenuToggle = () => this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })

  // Only close nav if it is open
  handleLinkClick = () => this.state.active && this.handleMenuToggle()

  toggleSubNav = subNav =>
    this.setState({
      activeSubNav: this.state.activeSubNav === subNav ? false : subNav
    })

  render() {
    const { active } = this.state,
    { subNav } = this.props,
      NavLink = ({ to, className, children, ...props }) => (
        <Link
          to={to}
          className={`NavLink ${
            to === this.state.currentPath ? 'active' : ''
          } ${className}`}
          onClick={this.handleLinkClick}
          {...props}
        >
          {children}
        </Link>
      )

    return (
      <nav className={`Nav ${active ? 'Nav-active' : ''}`}>

        <div className="Nav--Container container">
             <Link to="/" onClick={this.handleLinkClick}>
                <div style={{ width: `40px`, margin:`0 20px`}}>
                   <Logo />
                </div>
             </Link>

          <div className="Nav--Links">
          <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/contact/">Contacto</NavLink>

            <div className={`Nav--Group ${this.state.activeSubNav === 'about' ? 'active' : '' }`} > 

                 <span className={`NavLink Nav--GroupParent ${
                   this.props.location.pathname.includes('about') ||
                   this.props.location.pathname.includes('team') ||
                   this.props.location.pathname.includes('news') 
                   ? 'active'
                    : ''
                 }`} 
                       onClick={() => this.toggleSubNav('about')}
                 >
                     Nosotros
                 </span>
                 <div className="Nav--GroupLinks">
                    {subNav.map( (link, index)=> (
                        <NavLink 
                        to={link.link} 
                        key={'posts-subnav-link-' + index}
                        className="Nav--GroupLink">{link.name}</NavLink>
                    ))}
                 </div>

            </div>

          </div>

          <button
            className="Button-blank Nav--MenuButton"
            onClick={this.handleMenuToggle}
          >
            {active ? <X /> : <Menu />}
          </button>

        </div>

      </nav>
    )
  }
}

export default ({ subNav }) => (
  <Location>{route => <Navigation subNav={subNav} {...route} />}</Location>
)
```

the default position property is set to sticky in the nav.css file I want remove that and change it 
dynamically depending of the modal gallery state, open or close.

this is my gallery component:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Gallery from "react-photo-gallery";
import Carousel, { Modal, ModalGateway } from "react-images";

const PhotoGallery = ({photos}) => {
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);
  const [viewerIsOpen, setViewerIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const openLightbox = useCallback((event, { photo, index }) => {
    setCurrentImage(index);
    setViewerIsOpen(true);
  }, []);

  const closeLightbox = () => {
    setCurrentImage(0);
    setViewerIsOpen(false);
  };

   return(
     <div>
         <Gallery photos={photos} onClick={openLightbox} />
            <ModalGateway>
                {viewerIsOpen ? (
                   <Modal onClose={closeLightbox}>
                   <Carousel
                    currentIndex={currentImage}
                    views={photos.map(x => ({
                    ...x,
                    srcset: x.srcSet,
                    caption: x.title
                  }))}
            />
          </Modal>
        ) : null}
      </ModalGateway>
     </div>
   )
}

export default PhotoGallery
```

the problem is that when the modal is open the nav still sticky and does not allow me access to the modal controls, like close and expand...and I need to change that.

Comment: Where did you import the navigation component ? Maybe you should pass the viewerIsOpen parameter to the navigation component and listen it in componentDidUpdate method, and keep some css class info in state and change class name upon the viewerIsOpen parameter.

You can use classnames to do it.

Comment: I import the Nav component in to the Layout component...then I use the Layout in every page as a normal tag..and inside Layout I put the Gallery component

Comment: thanks for remember me about this question, Is solved. I used option 2 assigning styles via style prop. Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approaches to this.

1. **Old school classname toggling**

   Pass a prop down to the child component that reflects the state. On the child, use that prop to conditionally render one or more classes that represent the desired presentation.
2. **Assign styles via `style` prop**

   This is similar to #1, but eliminates a layer of abstraction. Instead of assembling a class list you just assemble the CSS styles you'd like to apply as an object.

   ```
   const Component = ({ someState }) => 
     <div style={someState ? { border: "5px solid red" } : { color: "#999" }}>
       Some Text
     </div>
   ```
3. **Use a CSS-in-JS library**

   The downside of the above approach is that you wind up duplicating styles for each instance of your element on the page. CSS-in-JS libraries solve this by extracting your styles into an automatically generated class and applying the class to your component instead. I prefer [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/), but there are others.

   Using Emotion you're able to accept a className prop from the parent that override the defaults set by the child. This inversion-of-control is really powerful and solves many of the shortcomings with early CSS-in-JS approaches.

   ```
   const ParentComponent = () => {
     const [someState] = useState(false)
     return <ChildComponent css={{ color: someState ? "blue" : "red" }} />
   }

   const ChildComponent = ({ className }) =>
     <div
       css={{
         color: "#000",
         border: "4px solid currentColor"
       }}
       className={className}
     >
       Some Text
     </div>
   ```

   In the above example, `className` is assigned by Emotion using the generated class name assigned based on the `css` prop passed to `ChildComponent` inside of `ParentComponent`. The result of this would be a `div` with a blue border and blue text when `someState` is `false` (default). When `someState` is switched to `true`, the border and text will be red. This is because the styles passed in via `className` will override the styles assigned directly via `css` in Emotion.